# Shall we get rid of the [type-ii-errors] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a tag [type-i-errors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type-i-errors) which covers Type 1 and Type 2 errors; that is very clear from the excerpt and the Wiki. There is also a tag [type-ii-errors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type-ii-errors) which seems to deal with Type 2 error specifically (has no Wiki, just an excerpt). I think it is redundant.

- First, Type 2 errors are already covered by [type-i-errors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type-i-errors).
- Second, if we wanted separate tags for separate types, than we should use [type-i-error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type-i-error) and [type-ii-error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type-ii-error) (singular) or probably [type-1-error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type-1-error) and [type-2-error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type-2-error) (singular and with Arabic numerals).

So shall we get rid of the [type-ii-errors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type-ii-errors) tag?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems pretty reasonable.  I suggest either:

1. I just make `[type-ii-errors]` a synonym of `[type-i-errors]` and merge them, or
2. make a new tag, `[type-i-&-ii-errors]`, and make both a synonym of that.

Upon reflection and discussion, I think #2 is best.

Comment: +1 from the OP. I think `[type-i-errors] ` can be understood to stand for $i=1,2$, so you would not need to create the `[type-1-&-2-errors]` tag, but perhaps this is not obvious to everyone.

Comment: @Richard I would find "type-i-errors" to be obscure and confusing.  Gung's idea of having two tags (as synonyms of each other and perhaps of yet more) is good, because it exploits the tags *already applied by users of the site.*  Those are the ones most likely to be used by future users in their searching.

Comment: @whuber, for clarity, you are arguing for making the new tag `i-&-ii`, right?

Comment: To be precise, originally you proposed `1-&-2`, not `i-&-ii`.

Comment: Gung: I advocate letting tags be determined organically by the proposers of questions, insofar as that is possible.  If a tag needs clarification, a good approach is to *leave it alone* but make it a synonym of another--preferably an existing one.  That suggests not creating any new tag in this case.

Comment: @whuber I don't understand what suggestion you are endorsing; you wrote that you "would find "type-i-errors" to be obscure and confusing" but that is exactly how the tag is currently called and you said you are against creating new tags in this case.

Comment: @amoeba Thank you for pointing that out.  I had misread some tags (the tag font shows up very small on this monitor for some reason).  Without context, "type-i-errors" strikes me as strange because it is reminiscent of a mathematical shorthand for "type 1, 2, 3, ..., whatever errors."   But that's me and I have to let the general principle override that: we ought to respect, and try to retain, whatever tags users originally pick.  However, there's nothing to prevent us from creating some (or even many) synonymous tags, such as "type-1-errors" or even "type-1-&-2-errors."

Comment: @whuber I see. I must say I do not agree with the general principle you are referring to. The tags are often suboptimal; once a suboptimal tag is created it will get used (remember that it requires some minimal reputation to be able to create a new tag) and there is no mechanism to ensure some sort of competition or survival of the fittest tags. I would agree that we should not delete existing tags (as a "weak form" of your principle). However, in my mind, nothing prevents us to create a new tag X and make an existing tag Y a synonym of X.

Comment: @amoeba Your thoughts have merit; I find them persuasive.  I still would like to hold out for the "weak principle," though, because that's part of what I promised when elected as moderator: to moderate lightly wherever possible.  Part of that means accepting the decisions of users whenever they do not clearly violate site policies or norms, even if I might disagree.

Comment: Is symbol "&" allowed in a tag name, @gung? I've never seen a tag with this symbol so I suspect that it isn't; if so, my preferred tag name would be `[type-i-and-ii-errors]`.

Comment: I tried: "&" does not work.

Comment: @amoeba, do you prefer the `i`'s or the Arabic numerals?

Comment: I prefer `i`'s as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors but this is not something that is very important to me.

Comment: @RichardHardy, are you OK w/ `[type-i-and-ii-errors]`, & making both existing tags synonyms of that? At this point, I think I might just go ahead if you're OK w/ it.

Comment: @gung, Besides `&` vs. `and` in the answer, all is well now (if amoeba is right that & cannot be used). Thank you.

Comment: It's done, @RichardHardy.